# A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'

Tags: android, launcher

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :launcher

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)